# How to store env variables other than inside gunicorn.service for a Django project?

Tags: python, django, bash, gunicorn

I tried putting all my environment variables for my Django project inside `~/.bash_profile` and then use it in gunicorn.service with `EnvironmentFile=/home/user/.bas...` but with no luck. Eventually I had to put everything in `ExecStart` with `-e` in front of every variable, also with SECRET_KEY and everything in plain text. Is it safe, is it possible to access this externally or how else could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.env` file and [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) package to handle your variables.

Comment: Does it serve them to all environments? It seems like gunicorn runs in its own environment since it can't get the variables, or I have entered wrong syntax, EnvironmentFIle=...

Comment: i don't have any experience with gunicorn. But with `python-dotenv` you can create `.env` file in your project, write down all your variables in it: `SECRET_KEY=very_secret...`, in django settings call `load_dotenv(find_dotenv())` and after this all variables from `.env` will be in the environment and you could access its with `os.environ` (for instance `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`)